# Devise .skip_confirmation! is not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have added a custom method to my (Devise) User controller:

```
def confirm
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.skip_confirmation!

    respond_to
        if @user.save 
            //display success message
        else
           // display error message
        end
    end
end
```

When I try to confirm a user via that, the save fails and I have two errors in @user.errors: password and password_confirm

Even in the rails console, if I try

```
@user.skip_confirmation!
@save
```

I get a rollback and the save fails.

Any ideas would be appreciated..

**Additional Info**

The problem causing this is the

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation
```

in my User model.  Even though a password and password confirmation was entered by the user on signup, those get hashed together to make the encrypted_password.  For example, when I find a user in the console, the user has an encrypted_password, but no password or password_confirmation.

I have tried this

```
validates_presence_of :password, :password_confirmation, :on => :create
```

However it doesn't force the user to enter both a password and a confirm on the Change Password screen.

Any idea on how to get around this?

Comment: Why do you have the check in a respond_to block? I don't think you want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding what `skip_confirmation!` does.

Devise's `confirmable` module will send a new user an e-mail with a link back to your app. Until they click that link, they'll be "unconfirmed" and unable to sign in. What `skip_confirmation!` does is skip this workflow -- the user will be immediately confirmed, and can log in without first having to go through the e-mail confirmation flow.

You're getting the error you're getting because of validations on the user model. In particular, the user you're trying to save doesn't appear to have an existing password, so it's requiring a `password` and matching `password_confirmation` attribute.

I suspect that there's a better way to accomplish whatever your purpose is. Why isn't the normal confirmation workflow sufficient? What's this extra controller action trying to accomplish?

Comment: The custom controller is so that I can give system administrators the ability to (administratively) confirm a user from within the Admin UI I have created.

Answer (score 0):

I think `skip_confirmation!` actually does the saving.

What you want to check is probably `if @user.persisted?`

Comment: This is incorrect, all `skip_confirmation!` does is `self.confirmed_at = Time.now.utc`

Comment: It also removes the confirmation token.